# How to configure a consumer(client) with Django Oauth Toolkit

Tags: python, django, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have 2 sites and I want to share the accounts between them, I found django oauth toolkit and I setup Site 1 as a server and I want Site 2 to be the client, Im following this tutorial https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial.html but I dont understand what I need to configure on Site 2 to login with the accounts of Site 1.

Im new to Django, and maybe Im omitting something obvious.